# Query points in circle areas

Tags: algorithm

Here is a picture  to illustrate the problem:[image: picture and features]

In the picture there are some feature points shown as blue crosses. I know the coordinate `(x,y)` for all of the features. Now I want to query which features are inside the circle area (green circle). In practice, there are around 500 features and 300 queries (300 different circles, different centers and radius). I know the parameters (position, radius) of circles. Is there any good algorithm which can do this task?

Current I have two ideas.

1. Most stupid one, just iterate through all of the features in each
   query. This is slower.
2. A rough idea. Separate the whole picture to some sub-pictures. Put features into a tree structure according to sub-pictures, if features in the same sub-pictures, then put in the same leaf. In each query, find out which sub-picture are covered by the circle and check all of the feature in these sub-pictures.

Does anyone out there have any better ideas?

Comment: The usual algorithmic-motivated approach is to use a metric-tree, like [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), which usually allows something like [query_ball_point](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point). This then results in building a tree of all your points and then call this function for each of your centers/radius. But your dataset is kind of small and it's hard to say if it will be faster or not. A well-implemented brute-force search might be fast too.

Comment: @sascha's approach is good but possibly a bit of work to implement if you don't already have a library for it.  A fairly easy, fairly quick solution would be to sort the crosses by, say, their x co-ordinate (choose y instead if the dataset is "tall and skinny").  Then for a circle of radius r centred at (x, y), you can binary search the array of crosses for x-r, then move rightward, checking each cross until you hit x+r.  (Every cross in the circle must lie in this x range.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker This is a quite nice idea. easy to implement and may fast enough. I would like to have a test.

Answer (score 3):

The most common way is to put the points into a K-D tree or similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

To find the points within a circle, you get the list of points in order of increasing distance from the center, and stop when the distance exceeds the circle radius.

To get list of points in order of increasing distance, you can use a priority queue that can hold both points and internal nodes of the tree, which lets you remove them in order of distance.

For points (leaves), the distance is just the distance of the point from the center point. For internal nodes, the distance is the smallest distance from the center point to any point that could possibly be in that node.

To search, you just put the root of the tree in the priority queue, and repeat:

1. Remove the head of the priority queue;
2. If the head of the queue was a point, then it is the closest point in the tree that you have not yet returned. You know this, because if any internal node could possibly have a closer point, then it would have been returned first from the priority queue;
3. If the head of the queue was an internal node, then put its children back into the queue

This will produce all the points in the tree in order of increasing distance from the center point.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. The idea looks like cool. The only thing I worry about is the processing time for my small data set. Because tree building may take lots of time. I am going to test such method with brute-force search method.

Comment: @Bigplume: kd trees are great if you have repeated distance lookups. If you are only ever doing it one time, then it's not really worth it to create the tree. Since you have 300 queries (and maybe it'll grow), whether or not to create a kd tree will be very CPU dependent.

Comment: Hi sir, what is the time complexity of query?

Comment: It's expected O(m + log n) for uniformly distributed points, where m is the size of the result set and n is the size of the point set.  For worst-case (adversarial) point distributions it can take O(n)