# Bark at a Sphere Tree or Look Somewhere Else?

Tags: data-structures, tree, logic

The scenario: A large number of players, playing a real-time game in 3d space, must be organized in a way where a server can efficiently update other players and any other observer of a players move and actions. What objects 'talk' to one another needs to be culled based on their range from one another in simulation; this is to preserve network sanity, programmer sanity, and also to allow for server-lets to handle smaller chunks of the overall world play-space.

However, if you have 3000 players, this runs into the issue that one must run 3000! Calculations to find out the ranges between everything. (Google tells me that ends up as a number with over 9000 digits; that’s insane and not worth considering for a near-real-time environment.)

Daybreak Games *seems* to have solved this problem with their massive online first person shooting game Planetside 2; it had allowed 3000 players to play on a shared space and have real-time responsiveness. They’ve apparently done it through a “Sphere Tree” data structure.

However, I’m not *positive* this is the solution they use, and I’m still a questioning how to apply the concept of "Sphere Trees" to reduce the range calculations for culling to a reasonable amount.

If Sphere Trees are not the right tree to bark up, what else should I be directing my attention at to tackle this problem?

(I'm a c# programmer (mainly), but I'm looking for a logical answer, not a code one)

References I’ve found about sphere trees;

http://isg.cs.tcd.ie/spheretree/#algorithms

https://books.google.com/books?id=1-NfBElV97IC&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few of my thoughts:
Let n denote the total number of players.

1. I think your estimate of 3000! is wrong. If you want to calculate all pairs distances given a fixed distance matrix, you run 3000 choose 2  operations, in the order of O(n^2*t), where t is the number of operations you spend calculating the distance between two players. If you build the graph underlying the players with edge weights being the Euclidean distance, you can reduce this to the all-pairs shortest paths problem, which is doable via the Floyd-Warshall algorithm in O(n^3).
2. What you're describing sounds pretty similar to doing a range query: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching. There are a lot of data structures that can help you, such as range trees and k-d trees.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those, and your right, I probably made a right mess of the question so thanks for wading through it

Comment: @Marky If you feel like it helped, could you maybe upvote it or mark it as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If objects only need to interact with objects that are, e.g., <= 100m away, then you can divide the world up into 100m x 100m tiles (or voxels), and keep track of which objects are in each non-empty tile.

Then, when one object needs to 'talk', you only need to check the objects in at most 9 tiles to see if they are close enough to hear it.

Comment: Right, I've had this thought, and for me following it out to its conclusion leads to Sphere Trees, because sphere trees divide the space up, but in a way that keeps load similar across different nodes (to my understanding at least).

Comment: Something like a sphere tree (although I would probably used a K-D tree or octree) would be better if different sorts of interactions have different maximum ranges.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699240/query-points-in-circle-areas/50705109#50705109 .   For fixed ranges, though, tiles are simpler and faster.  Instead of a tree you just need a hashmap from tile location to list of occupants, for non-empty tiles only.