# Data structure for spatial closeness queries

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

#### Limitations

- Memory is not an issue, as long as it fits on a normal PC. I'm not trying to optimize memory usage here.
- Update speed is extremely important, then query speed.

#### Problem to solve

I have a world of tasks, each tied to an actual world object (ie, cut this tree, build this wall, carry this resource to storage, etc). So any resource drop can trigger an update.

I also have actors which periodically ask for tasks to do, and the tasks they choose to do is the closest one to them in physical space that they can both do and are prioritized to do. So the closest task isn't always the answer, I need a potential stream of tasks ordered correctly that I can pick my task from.

Naively, I can (and did) implement this as a for loop over every task in the world sorted by linear distance to the actor, filtering out every task that the actor cannot physically do, and I keep track of the best task found for each task category until I either find a task of the highest priority, or I run out of tasks in which case I pick the highest priority task I did find.

I'm looking for a data structure to help me avoid ordering the entire world of tasks by their distance to every actor in every cycle. Things I've considered and dropped:

- Octree & friends. It's very good at answering collision queries, ie queries against specific points in space. That's not what I want, I want to give it one point (my actor) and get tasks closest to farthest away from it, potentially all of them (but usually just a small subset).
- Forcing octree & friends anyway. I considered a spiral pattern search against the octree centered on my actor, with increasingly larger distances. I could get it to work, but I'm not convinced that's much of an improvement, and it definitely feels hacky. I'm holding hope that there's a better data structure out there.

Comment: As far as I know K nearest neighbors is not a simple thing to do generally. There’s algorithms and ways to handle out there, maybe the term already gives some info to help select how to handle it. One way might be good for specific data, another for other kind of data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699240/query-points-in-circle-areas/50705109#50705109

Comment: That question is about querying objects in a bounding box (or circle), I have no bounds, I want potentially *all* objects in the world.

Comment: Heh.  The answer I directed you to describes the procedure for getting all points in order of increasing distance.

Comment: The usual for this job would be an [r-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). It's vaguely similar to an octree, but generally better suited to this sort of task.